# Display Name not changing

Tags: content-editor

Sitecore 8.2 update 0

I have a few items in my tree that when I try and change the display name, nothing happens. The display name stays the same. On the Audit of the change in the logs. No error.

> 11848 16:51:23 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): Set display name: master:/sitecore/content/sites/client/settings/authors/john-doe, language: en, version: 1, id: {F808FA41-3483-4334-8DF1-CB1AD1079F56}, name: fffff

I created a brand new Sitecore site, copied over the connectionstrings.config and updated the data path. No extra configs at all. Still does it. It seems like its in the DB.

Any cache I am missing?

#### Update 1

Just an update that I did/do have item:saved event that updates the item name and display to convert spaces to "-".

I have opened a Sitecore ticket. I will update here if they come back with anything.

#### Update 2

Looking at the database I found that in UnversionedFields, I found two records for display name. One with a language and one without. The one without the language is the one being shown. The one with a language is the one being updated.

[image]

Comment: You know... I recall someone in Slack having this exact same issue, and it boiled down to some kind of corruption in one of the databases. It was a while back.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850067/unable-to-change-display-name-of-item-why

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Couldn't find any display name field items that were being versioned or shared.

Comment: Question on Update 1 - Why are you converting spaces to dashes on item name ***and*** display name? Or are you just modifying display name?  On a different note, if you want authors to be able to use dashes in Sitecore, you could remove the dash from the `InvalidItemNameChars` setting. Just a thought.

Comment: I followed this from Jammy a little while back. The character replacement can cause issues with medial library items. Its also hard to come into a site that has a lot of items with -'s and make them illegal. So I just convert the item name to lower case and spaces to "-", but leave the Display Name the same. https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/07/13/seo-friendly-urls-in-sitecore-prevention-is-better-than-cure/

Comment: Fair enough! Yup, that's perfectly fine. Dashes are always an interesting footnote to me when it comes to item names. I still think you have something funky going on with your database. I'm trying to recall what the fix was. It didn't happen to me, so I'm forgetting. But it echoed of some kind of database issue that didn't get resolved until either they replaced it with a database from before the issue, or they started over with a fresh database. (either scenario is probably not optimal). That being said, Alessandro's answer might be helpful, as Serializing resets items.

Comment: 95% of the items are fine, just a few are off. I have not found anything interesting in my SQL investigation yet. Maybe I should have taken Jammy's post the end and implemented the rules engine to handle naming,

Comment: Have you try changing the display name from the appearance section in standard fields?

Comment: When I update it and press save, it puts it back. http://recordit.co/LRARlhR88j

Comment: Are you wrapping your edition of the item in an EventDisabler()? If so, this disables several things like the update of the display name in the the Content Tree, index update, among other things. If you collapse the parent item and expand it again, you will see it changed - only if this is the cause of course.

Comment: No event disabler. Just a normal BeginEdit, EndEdit().

Comment: I have similar issue, but on Sitecore 9.2, production environment - MASTER DB only. I went trough your previous comments and I can not fix this. 1. [VersionedFields] and [SharedFields] do not contain this field
2. There's no code added to item:saving or item:saved events in configuration
3. [UnersionedFields] table contains this field but it have language code populated correctly so I should not remove it Are there any more ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason why this is happening to some items is that the items might be corrupted.

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM [your db].[dbo].[VersionedFields]
WHERE ItemId = 'one of your funky items'
  AND FieldId = '{B5E02AD9-D56F-4C41-A065-A133DB87BDEB}'
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM [your db].[dbo].[SharedFields]
WHERE ItemId = 'one of your funky items'
  AND FieldId = '{B5E02AD9-D56F-4C41-A065-A133DB87BDEB}'
```

Since `__Display Name` is neither versioned or shared, nothing should come up on these queries. But if I am right, something will - and you should just proceed to delete these rows.

You may also delete the row from the Unversioned result where the item is not the correct one and update the other fields like the language. Do this for only this item as a test. If it works, you may consider of updating the other corrupted items.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850067/unable-to-change-display-name-of-item-why

Answer (score 2):

(I wish I could comment...but I cannot yet)

I have experienced a similar issue for one of my projects on a lower environment using Sitecore 6.6. The fact that this issue occurred on one single environment (and not in production or other lower environments) seems to confirm what Pete suggested.

This doesn't answer your question about what it is causing this, but I was able to find a manual workaround. I recall I was able to change the display name of an item using the serialization developer tools though. Serialize the item, make a manual change in the serialized file to the display name (and to the count value of the field), revert the serialized item in Sitecore.